# jQuery instead of Flash animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I'm trying to find a way to replace the flash animaton on this page http://www.autopulsen.se/ into jQuery. I could cut the images out and rotate them with javascript but it would require major changes in code. Basically I want to keep the same look without flash.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it can be done, when you mouse over it changes the image which you can done through jquery and also apply animate function to show the text below it like that.

Comment: you could make equivalent animation with javascript using Sencha Animator. link: http://www.sencha.com/products/animator. if u are familiar with Flash though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Your starting point would be having a look at [this site](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-image-zoom.html), there are a lot of zoom plugins on there, which is the main feature of that flash menu. Then you would want to chain the [JQuery Shake](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake) effect, and maybe look at the [fade](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Fade) effect.

To achieve the slanted look you will want to use the skew css selector as featured [here](http://www.css3files.com/transform/#skew).

Comment: Thank you. Any tip on how to lean the images in the same way? Each of the five "sections" should be an individual image with a link. I am not allowed to change the design.

Comment: You can use the skew css selector to lean items e.g    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);

Comment: Will this be displayed properly on mobile devices?

Comment: Well, the transform2d css required for skew is supoprted on major ios and android, check : http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you've saved me hours of pain.

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw in GreenSock Animation Platform:

[www.greensock.com/gsap-js](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js)

which may be worth a look, especially if there's the option of paying for a commercial license, as that includes a pretty nifty throwProps plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS3 animation but this one i think so good and hard to built in css3 
anyway 
giving you some animation generator

- [ceaser](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/)
- [CSS3animationGenrator](http://www.css3animationgenerator.com/)
- [Css3Maker](http://www.css3maker.com/css3-animation.html)

and this one for Inspiration

- [At DesignShack](http://designshack.net/articles/css/10-amazing-examples-of-innovative-css3-animation/)